# Global Maximizer for log-likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, kalman-filter, likelihood

OK simply I have the following model:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x_k & = f(x_{k-1},\theta)+q_{k-1}\\
y_k & = h(x_k,\theta)+r_k
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}

Using Matlab, I generated some data artificially (simulated data) with a vector of parameters $\theta = [\theta_1,...,\theta_n]$ (supposed the true parameters).

I used Gaussian filtering to calculate The log-likelihood expression:

$L(\theta) =  \sum_{k=1}^T -\frac{1}{2}\log [(2\pi)^d\vert \Sigma_k\vert] - \frac{1}{2}(y_k-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}_k (y_k-\mu)
$

The parameters $\mu=\hat{y}_{k|k-1}$ and $\Sigma=P_{yy,k|k-1}$ are computed during the Gaussian filtering and $d$ is the observation dimension.

The simple question why the true values of the parameters do not maximize the log-liklihood? (is it possible that this happens?).

Comment: What do you mean by 'the true parameters'? If the parameters that generate the data, (obviously?) neither MLE nor any other parameter estimation method can magically recover them from a finite sequence of noisy observations

Comment: This question seems very similar to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249626/

Comment: Yes the true parameters are the parameters used to generate the data, my question is similar to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81591/log-likelihood-at-true-parameters  and http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Negative+logLikelihood+Kalman+filter

Comment: From what's here, it's hard to know what answer could be given, but in the sense that the data are random, the parameter estimates that maximize the log-likelihood of a given sample will not be the true parameters, but should converge to the true parameters if the samples are unbiased as the sample size tends to infinity.